# TransactionManager / UserTransaction do not reflect changes in my database - @Transactional does. Why?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, quarkus, jta

I would like to **find an entity, update one of its properties, and then delete it. All in one REST call**. While it may seem odd at first, updating the entity will trigger a procedure in my DB.

The challenge is that those two operations need to take place in **different transactions**, because otherwise the trigger will not pick up the update statement.

So far I have tried many things, and while I managed to achieve my goal, the resulting code felt clumsy, and trying alternative methods raised a couple of questions.

But first, consider this code.

My Controller:

```
@Path("/offer")
public class OfferController {

    @Inject
    OfferService offerService;    

    @DELETE
    public Response deleteOffer(@PathParam("offerId") @NotNull UUID offerId) {
        Offer entity = Offer.findById(offerId); // Offer extends BaseEntity extends PanacheEntityBase
        offerService.deleteOffer(entity);
        return Response.ok().entity(offerId).build();
    }
}
```

My offer service as I want it to be:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class OfferService {

    @Inject
    DeletionService deletionService;
    
    public void deleteOffer(Offer offer) {
        deletionService.deleteEntity(offer);
    }

}
```

My deletion service as I want it to be:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class DeletionService {

    @Inject
    TransactionManager tm;

    public void deleteEntity(BaseEntity baseEntity) {

        // This has no effect in the DB, my entity is unchanged
        tm.begin();
        baseEntity.deletedBy = "Current User Id";
        tm.commit();

    
        // Adding this leads to a RollbackException (Cannot register synchronization because the transaction is in aborted state)
        tm.begin();
        baseEntity.delete();
        tm.commit();    
    }

}
```

I also tried injecting and using the **UserTransaction** as described [in the docs](https://quarkus.io/guides/transaction), but it resulted in the same errors. **What is the difference, and when do I need which?** I find the documentation rather confusing.

---

Since I could not get the manual transaction management to work, I managed to make it work using the declarative approah, after (finally) understanding the [transaction propagation](https://fullstackfront.com/2019/03/31/jpa-transaction-management.html) and its [limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68199750/does-transactional-txtype-requires-new-start-a-new-transaction-when-called-from)

My actual deletion service:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class DeletionService {

    @Inject
    CurrentUser currentUser;

    @Inject
    EntityManager em;

    @Transactional(Transactional.TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public BaseEntity setDeletedBy(BaseEntity baseEntity) {
        BaseEntity merge = em.merge(baseEntity);
        merge.deletedBy = currentUser.userId;
        merge.persist();
        return merge;
    }
    
    @Transactional(Transactional.TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void doDelete(BaseEntity baseEntity) {
        BaseEntity merge = em.merge(baseEntity);
        merge.delete();
    }
}
```

My actual offer service:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class OfferService {

    @Inject
    DeletionService deletionService;
    
    public void deleteOffer(Offer offer) {
        BaseEntity updated = deletionService.setDeletedBy(offer); // TX 1
        deletionService.doDelete(updated); // TX 2
    }    
}
```

This works as intended. But I feel it is unnecessarily complex.

---

So I feel like I am missing something here. Why does my manual transaction management not work? **In my Tests I am using the TransactionManager like this, and it works just fine**:

```
    @Test
    public void myTest() throws Exception {

        @Inject
        TransactionManager tm;

        tm.begin();
        Offer newOffer = offerService.createNewOffer();
        tm.commit();

        tm.begin();
        Offer.findById(newOffer.id).delete();
        tm.commit();
}
```

Comment: As far as I know Transactionmanager is used for Containermanaged Transactions. You need to use UserTransaction. https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/transaction/UserTransaction.html

Comment: I tried both, and in my services they both do not work as I wanted. But in my tests, the TransactionManager works. Besides, Quarkus Docs mention both: https://quarkus.io/guides/transaction

Comment: I don't know Quarkus. But in the docs you linked I noticed two things: 1. The Sentence ```You cannot use UserTransaction in a method having a transaction started by a @Transactional call```  2. The fact that ```@Transactional(REQUIRED)``` is default. So maybe you need to annotate your deleteEntity-method with ```@Transactional(NOT_SUPPORTED)``` to be able to use UserTransaction.

Comment: @frank `@Transactional(REQUIRED)` is the default when you write only `@Transactional` - but not if you omit it. Then, no transaction is started. But I will give `@Transactional(NOT_SUPPORTED)` a try.